# How do I re-enable disabled network notifications in GNOME Shell?

Tags: 12.04, networking, gnome, notification

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. 
 I recently disabled (accidentally pressed "don't show again" button) some network notification on GNOME Shell. There are (as I can remember):

1. "GSM Network - You are now registered on the home network"
2. "`<Network Profile>` - Connection established"

Now both on Unity and GNOME Shell, those notifications didn't showed up, and it felt just wrong.
What can I do to re-enable those disabled notifications? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 12.10 - Dconf

Run these commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-disconnected-notifications "false"
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-connected-notifications "false"
```

Or open [dconf-editor [image: Install dconf-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) and scroll down to `org` ▸ `gnome` ▸ `nm-applet` and uncheck `disable-connected-notifications` and `disable-disconnected-notifications` settings there.

[image: DConf]

---

### 11.10 and 12.04 - Gconf

[gconf-editor](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gconf-editor) [image: Install gconf-editor] lets you edit the network manager notifications.

Scroll to `/ ▸ apps  ▸ nm-applet` and uncheck `disable-connected-notifications` settings there.

[image: Gconf]

Or the command line method:

```
gconftool -s /apps/nm-applet/disable-disconnected-notifications --type=bool false
gconftool -s /apps/nm-applet/disable-connected-notifications --type=bool false
```

Comment: Okay I had it fixed, wrong actions before, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**GNOME** is transitioning to **dconf** instead, edit with `dconf-editor` from apt package `dconf-tools`. Settings for `nm-applet` are at `/org/gnome/nm-applet`.

Comment: Can you explain what settings exactly to change?